# Use sed to filter output from git log

Tags: git, bash, svn, sed

I did some svn to git migration. Now I use git log to find the svn revision (which is described in the commit message of git).

```
$ git log -1 11.10.11.0
```

output

```
commit 84a1f5fb6xxx4607e6ed5623eab15ecdbacf
Author: USER <USER>
Date:   Wed Apr 12 08:27:08 2017 +0000

    git-svn-id: https://svn-repo.com/repo/proj/tags/11.10.11.0@12000 f25b8xx2b0-ax00-41x2-87xx1-abxxxxe8fa
```

Now I want to use sed to filter the revision number (`12000`) in this case. What's the most generic way to do this?

Comment: What did you try for yourself? post it even if its a trivial one. And why are you restricting yourself to `sed`? `Awk` or `grep` could be equally useful here

Comment: @DenCowboy check the alternate approach with `sed` as `-P` flag in grep is not available to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` approach: Here `sed` two actions are performed by sed. One is to only print the desired line and other is to print the desired section of line.

```
<git-command>|sed -r '/git-svn-id/!d;s/.*@([^ ]+).*/\1/'
12000
```

If `grep` is acceptable approach to you:

```
<git-command>|grep -oP 'git-svn-id.*?@\K[^ ]+'
12000
```

If `awk` is acceptable:

```
<git-command>|awk '/git-svn-id/{n=split($2,a,"@");print a[n]}'
12000
```

Answer (score 1):

The `awk` command can meet your requirement, take a look at below,

```
git log -1 11.10.11.0 | awk -F'@' '{printf "%s",$2}' | awk '{print $1}'
12000
```